# which distance function between two different variables?

Tags: distribution, euclidean-distance, metric

What is the best metric to calculate the distance between two objects? The objects are represented by four paremeters (two same variables before and after a procedure).

The goal is to assign data points as pairs among the whole set. Additionally  the data points of each pair shall be as close/similar to each other.

[image: The data]

Normal and normalized distribution: Look the same just with different magnitudes on the axis.

[image: Feature scaling]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any measurement function. Most often, people use the euclidean distance but the optimal one depends heavily on the situation. Otherwise, you can always try all the functions to observe which is the most accurate.

Something I would recommend doing is scaling your features (if you have more than one). By scaling your features, you can decide how much "impact" each feature has in the euclidean formula.

If you have a feature that appears to be much more important than another one, you can scale it to a slightly larger number. If all your features are equal weight, you should scale them all down to the same range of numbers, which is often `[-0.5, 0.5]`.

Comment: What is a measurement function? For the metric? I did the scaling up to now for the calculation of the distance but I should probably do it before to get a feeling of the distribution. In case of a more important parameter: How exactly take this into account? I divide this paremeter less then the other ones? E.g. "Important parameter / 10" and "less important parameter / 20" ?

Comment: The measurement function or distance function is how your distance is measured (euclidean, jaccard). How the scaling is done depends on the initial range of the features. Yes, if the initial range of both features are the same (ie. [-0.5 - 0.5]), then you can divide the less important parameter by more, or alternatively, multiply the more important parameter by more.

Comment: Ah, thanks, so just the distance. Ok, thanks again. In my case it is obvious (is it?) that the data points are not normally distributed so I guess an euclidean distance is not the best? The mahalanobis distance looks quite good but I'm not really sure what is going on there. Does it only calculate how far a point is away from the center or can I really calculate the distance between two points? And hence, I read somewhere that Jaccard is allegedly the best for finding the nearest neighbor. But I do not find any information.

Comment: Oftentimes, the shape of the graph has more to do with "curve-fitting" than choosing the right distance function. In your case, the mahalanobis distance is simply measuring how many "standard deviations" away the point is from the mean, I don't think it id particularly useful for this algorithm. The Jaccard index is also not a great metric for your example because the "objects" being compared are purely numerical, there is no binary groups involved. As for the normalization of data, you can use non-linear regression.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do I get the best non-linear approach? Shall the distribution become flat resp. a line?

Comment: I'm not sure if is (not) the same: The euclidean distance can be represented as a circle. I guess in this case an ellipse would fit quite well. How can I construct that?

Comment: I guess I got what I need but just to ensure respectively about my motivation: I want to assign two data points in such a way that each element of a pairing is as close as possible to the other element. And each data point is made of four parameters. Is the approach above still the most sensefull? To be fair I just took a plot with two variables because it is more easy do comprehend but I guess the amount of dimensions makes no difference?

Comment: I still thought a little bit about it and I'm afraid that I didn't get with respect to my thoughts in the origin: Why is mahalanobis not useful? And how shall I flatten a four-dimensional distribution?

Comment: The mahalanobis distance would definitely help since it is unit-less and scale-invariant especially if you want to take all points into consideration. You should test it out to see whether it works better than feature scaling. Whereas if you are solving the classification problem, (given features [x, y, z] what is it?) then the euclidean distance is ideal.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why the euclidean is ideal? I feel uncomfortable because it is the most naive way and in most of my experiences the solutions were not :) And especially what it makes better than mahalanobis. And also how do I know if that is, in return, better than feature scaling? Lot of thanks in advance!

Comment: Earlier when your question was tagged under "nearest-neighbor", I thought you were referring to the algorithm in which case I would suggest euclidean distance. However, if you are simply measuring the similarity index, then by all means, if you aren't satisfied with the Euclidean metric - use the mahalanobis metric.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I thought nearest-neighbor refers to a topic, not to an algorithm in specific. My problem is that I don't know how to choose a proper metric. Can I calculate the distance between two points with mahalanobis? I often read that it is used between two groups and for outliers.

Comment: Yes, per se. You are trying to find the similarity between two vectors. These vectors are your n-dimensional data "point". This is a great metric to use because it accounts for the normalization of each distinct feature scale (whereas in Euclidean metric, you have to scale it yourself). The covariance matrix takes care of this for you.

Comment: But be aware that if you have a very high feature to data point ratio, the covariance matrix for computing the mahalanobis distance is very inaccurate and subject to great change whereas the euclidean distance is unaffected by the amount of data points. Basically you need a substantial number of data points for the mahalanobis distance to be useful.

Comment: Thanks, so probably the last final question, just to be sure (so much going on in my head right now): I now go for the mahalanobis distance to measure the distance between two vectors based on four different parameters. Right?

Comment: Yes, each of your vectors would have a size of 4.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! One question more (saw it after I posted before): Substantial means? I have 1300 data points, is that good?

Comment: It looks like a good enough ratio since you have a very small number of features. In general the danger comes when you have say 50 features and only 60 data points, then your matrix may not be very accurate.

Comment: Ah! Well, thank you very much! You cleared a lot of thoughts I wasn't able to separate.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a "mahalanobis distance" between two points, a bit of feature scaling is probably your best bet. Also, nearest-neighbor does not appear to be the best algorithm to use in this problem.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain the mahalanobis distance in this context? I know it is normally used to idenfity outliers by calculating the distance to the center of a set with the help of its standard deviations. But in one or two sources I also saw that they calculated the distance of two points relative to each other.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling I already do this. I calculate the difference between the same parameter of both data points and divide it by a certain tolerance limit (scaling to unit length in the wikipedia article). Then the same with the other parameters and then I calculate the hypotenuse out of this four normalized distances. Didn't know this is a standard procedure..  but anyhow the tolerance limit is the same for all parameters so the distribution of all data points stays being not homogenous therefore I think I still have to take this into account. Or not?

Comment: I added a plot to the question

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: To assign data points as pairs among the whole set. With the condition that the data points of each pair are as close/similar to each other.

Comment: if you just place two points together, wouldn't they be close/similar to each other?

Comment: The data points represent real measurements. The question is "How do I calculate / measure the similarity / difference?"

Comment: as @yelq pointed out, you can scale your features by using sqrt(x), x^2.. etc, it doesn't need to be linear. You can even make one feature equal to the product of all the features.

Comment: How do I know if sqrt(x) or x^2 is better? And what is the goal for feature scaling?